# How to deploy npm workspace package separately

Tags: git, npm, git-submodules, npm-workspaces

There is a project with two registered subprojects pulled into the project by git submodules. When workspaces/submodules are pushed to GitHub it is not possible to install packages without the parent package.json. Is it possible to generate package-lock.json for a workspace to make them independent?
The main reason for workspaces now is to synchronize package versions and keep them up to date. Does another tool exist for it?

According documentation

```bash
.
+-- node_modules
|  `-- workspace-a -> ../workspace-a
+-- package-lock.json
+-- package.json
`-- workspace-a
   `-- package.json
```

It installs everything into the parent workspace and does not generate `package-lock.json` for workspaces. So I have to refuse to git submodules.